# diff equation for object sinking in water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, differential-equations

I am trying to solve this problem but making a mistake somewhere. The problem is      the following.

An object weighing W =1000 lb sinks in water starting from rest. Two forces act on it, a buoyant force of B = 200 lb and a force of water resistance that numerically equal to R=100 v, where v in ft/sec. Find the distance traveled after 5 sec and the limiting velocity.

$F = ma = W - R - B$
$\frac{1000}{32}a = 1000 - 100v - 200$
$\frac{5}{16}a = 8 - v$
$\frac{5}{16}\frac{dv}{dt} = 8 - v$
$\frac{dv}{8 - v}= \frac{16}{5}{dt}$
$\int\limits_{0}^{v}\frac{dv}{8 - v} =\int\limits_{0}^{t}\frac{16}{5}{dt} $
After solving I get $v = 8 - 8E^\frac{16}{5}{t}$

Which is not correct since the E power is positive.... Are the forces signs correct?